# How to navigate to a new page with query string parameters in next.js 13 (app dir)

Tags: next.js

In the old `pages` version of Next.js I used to be able to navigate to a new page like this

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router"
const q = {
  foo: "red cat",
  bar: true
}
router.push({ pathname: '/blah', query: q })
```

How can I accomplish the same thing with the [new router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router)?

### What I've tried

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation"
const q = {
  foo: "red cat",
  bar: true
}
router.push('/blah', { query: q })
```

but this doesn't inject the query params.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/76243094/15288641.

Comment: Thanks, I just found that in [the docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params#updating-searchparams). I guess the idea is to build the full URL string yourself by leveraging [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams).