# how to query items from useRouter() hock in case i'm using nextjs with App Router approach

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

**This was the way to do it using Pages Router**

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

import React from "react";

function ShowroomListings({}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { listingId } = router.query as { listingId: string };

  return <div>This is item No. {listingId}</div>;
}

export default ShowroomListings;
```

[Failed to compile message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNALp.png)

Now I imported useRouter from "next/navigation" this time, but '.query' will not work anymore

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import React from "react";

function ShowroomListings({}) {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { listingId } = router.query as { listingId: string };

  return <div>This is item No. {listingId}</div>;
}

export default ShowroomListings;
```

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76242781/how-to-change-and-add-query-strings-in-the-app-folder-of-next-js.

Answer (score 1):

`useRouter` only works on client-component (while your component is a server-component). You can add `'use client'` directive to top of the file to use `useRouter`.

Update:

- The `query` object has been removed and is replaced by `useSearchParams`

Reference:

1. [Next.js useRouter](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-router)
2. [Next.js 'use client' directive](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#the-use-client-directive)
3. [Next.js useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params)

Comment: "use client" was added actually as the error goes

Comment: Ah I've checked the docs. The `query` object has been removed. You can use `useSearchParams` instead. 
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use useRouter hook in server component, because it is a client side hook. You need to make you component client inorder to get query parameters.

```
'use client'
```

also nextjs introduce new hook for query parameters which is useSearchParams, you can easily get query param with.

```
const params = useSearchParms()
params.get("query-parameter-name")
```

Answer (score -1):

it worked for me

```js
import React from "react";

type ShowroomProps = {
  params: {
    listingId: string;
  };
};

export default function ShowroomListings({
  params: { listingId },
}: ShowroomProps) {
  return <div>This is item No. {listingId}</div>;
}
```

just passing the right dynamic route value